# Converte um valor decimal para inteiro em C#?

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo, decimal, inteiros

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
decimal n = 12.96m;
int i = (int)n;
int b = Convert.ToInt32(n);
    
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

que tem a seguintes saídas:

```
12 // referente Console.WriteLine(i)
13 // referente Console.WriteLine(b)
```

Esse resultado nos mostra que o método contido na classe [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-7.0) acaba arrendondando o número para cima e o casting o resultao é sem arrendodamento sendo assim de uma forma geral mais apropriado.

*Perguntas*

- Sintaticamente qual é a maneira correta de tratar essa conversão de decimal para inteiro?
- Existe uma melhor forma de fazer a conversão de decimal para inteiro que não estão contidos nesses dois códigos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sintaticamente qual é a maneira correta de tratar essa conversão de decimal para inteiro?

A sintaxe em ambos os casos está correta. Entretanto, os métodos de conversão são diferentes, o primeiro usa uma [conversão explícita](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-expression), enquanto que o outro faz uso da **classe auxiliar** `System.Convert`.

Essencialmente o segundo caso faz uso do primeiro método, mas resolveu - por qualquer motivo - adotar uma estratégia de arredondamento, como pode ver no código fonte desse método em particular:

```
public static int ToInt32(double value) {
    if (value >= 0) {
        if (value < 2147483647.5) {
            int result = (int)value; // Uso de conversão explícita
            double dif = value - result;
            if (dif > 0.5 || dif == 0.5 && (result & 1) != 0) result++;
            return result;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (value >= -2147483648.5) {
            int result = (int)value; // Uso de conversão explícita
            double dif = value - result;
            if (dif < -0.5 || dif == -0.5 && (result & 1) != 0) result--;
            return result;
        }
    }
    throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
}
```

Fonte: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1087

> Existe uma melhor forma de fazer a conversão de decimal para inteiro que não estão contidos nesses dois códigos?

Não. Nesse caso, esses dois são os únicos métodos possíveis. Outras alternativas podem acabar resultando em uma conversão indireta, mas se cavar fundo o suficiente eventualmente vai encontrar o uso da conversão explícita, que é obrigatória na conversão de `decimal` para `int` porque os limites e especificação do primeiro tipo são mais abrangentes do que o segundo:

| Tipo | Intervalo | Tamanho |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-7.0) | -79.228.162.514.264.337.593.543.950.335 até 79.228.162.514.264.337.593.543.950.335 | 16 bytes |
| [int](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=net-7.0) | -2.147.483.648 até 2.147.483.647 | 4 bytes |

Isso faz com que eventualmente algum dado seja perdido no processo de conversão (como foi o caso das decimais, como você viu no resultado do método 1), ou ainda o tipo de destino (`int`) seja incapaz de suportar o dado resultante da conversão, causando uma `OverflowException`.

Answer (score 1):

Quando um *type cast* (conversão explícita) é feito para converter um valor decimal para um tipo inteiro, o valor será sempre arredondado para 0. Mais detalhes [aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#explicit-numeric-conversions).

Contudo, como muito bem mostrou o Diego na resposta dele acima, a partir da conversão explícita é possível elaborar uma lógica para arredondar o valor final para 0 ou para 1 de acordo com a regra de arredondamento convencional (valores decimais > 0 e < 0,5 arredondam para 0, enquanto valores decimais >= 0,5 e < 1 arredondam para 1).

Com relação a uma dessas formas ser a melhor para converter de decimal para inteiro, a resposta é: depende da aplicação. Ela é quem vai te dar a base para definir qual conversão será melhor no seu caso.

Comment: Olá, @AugustoVasques. Será revisado. Obrigado pela indicação.